# Moving site from IIS 6 to IIS 7.5, Internet Explorer chops the long urls only on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have two physical servers.  The old one runs an ASP.NET site on IIS 6 (Windows 2003) and it works properly.  I just moved the site over to the new server running IIS 7.5 (Windows 2008 R2 x64) and have it running on there.

Everything seems to be working, except that when a user tries to open a page with a long URL, Internet explorer chops the url short.  It works fine in Firefox and Chrome and it works with IE getting the page from the old server.  I confirmed it by doing a packet capture and seeing that the HTTP Get request did have the URL chopped short.   It appears that IE treats IIS 6 and IIS 7.5 different since the site works fine on IIS 6 when using Internet Explorer.  Tried both IE8 and IE9 with no difference.

Is there some way to force Internet Explorer to use the full URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that Internet Explorer always chops long urls (but Firefox and Chrome don't).  The reason I had this problem is the new server name was 4 characters longer and that was causing the chopping to happen in a place that broke the site.

msdn doc about IE maximum url length: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427